# Read and parse logic in dictionary format

Tags: python, logic

I'm trying to store some logic in dictionary format, then have a Python parser that read and evaluate, for example, in my dictionary I have

```
rule_dict = {
    'logic': 'equal',
    'value': '1'
}
```

And my parser is defined and used like below

```
def test_data_against_rule_dict(rule_dict, data):
    if rule_dict['logic'] == 'equal'
        return rule_dict['value'] == data
    elif ...

data = 1
result = test_data_against_rule_dict(rule_dict, data)
# result = True
```

I need to handle other logic like `not equal`, `is in given list`, `not in given list` etc. I can define the name of these logic myself and write the parser for each logic myself, but I wonder if there's existing standard or Python library I can use directly.

Adding another example to explain another one of my use cases, e.g. for the `not in given list` example:

```
rule_dict = {
    'logic': 'exclude',
    'value': '1'
}

def test_data_against_rule_dict(rule_dict, data):
    if rule_dict['logic'] == 'equal'
        return rule_dict['value'] == data
    elif rule_dict['logic'] == 'exclude'
        return rule_dict['value'] not in data
    ...

data = [1,2,3]
result = test_data_against_rule_dict(rule_dict, data)
# result = False
```

Comment: I've many times hoped that `math` module would contain these basic concepts so I could store functions in dictionaries and operate on them. But sadly you'll have to set these things up by yourself. You could create a set of functions called `equal` and store it in a dict, something along the lines of `rule_map = {'equal' : equal}` and call it accordingly: `rule_map[rule_dict['logic']](rule_dict['value'], data)`. But there's no built in library for this, no :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any library to solve this task. However, you could use the eval method for less code (but the execution will be slower):

Change your rule_dict to the code that should be executed, like this:

```
rule = '1 not in data'
```

Your check becomes simple then:

```
return eval(rule)
```

Comment: data is a variable though, it's dynamic

Comment: Yeah and here comes the trick of eval. Eval does actually run the code. If you call eval(rule) the interpreter will run the line "1 not in data" and use the variable called "data".

Comment: See https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval

Comment: Yeah but keep in mind, that this is slow as hell. So if the execution speed is critical you want to avoid this.